# Compare and match single column of 2 files and display all columns/rows of both files using awk command unix

Tags: shell, awk, compare, solaris, columnsorting

I got file 1 appear like this:

```
 40 / 3 / Swimming / Outdoor Sport
 40 / 4 / Badminton / Indoor Sport
 40 / 8 / Bowling Game / Indoor Sport
 40 / 12 / Football / Team Sport
 40 / 20 / Diving / Water Aquatic Sport
 40 / 22 / Karting / Driving  Activity
 40 / 30 / Martial Art / Exhibition Show
 128 / 3 / Bacon / Fast Food
 128 / 4 / Hamburger / Fast Food
 128 / 5 / French Fries / Fast Food
 128 / 6 / Cola/ Soft Drink
 128 / 8 / Bacon / Fast Food
 128 / 9 / Spicy Fried Chicken /Restaurant Food Store
 128 / 12 / Traditional Pizza / Restaurant Food Store

 Another file let name it as file 2 that appeared at this format:

 Georgetown /Family/Event /40/Name of Activity/Date of Activity/Note/Sign/Confirm/
 Ferrytown /Family/Event /128/Null/Null/Null/Null/
 Ferrytown /Family/Event /128/Name of Activity/Date of Activity/Note/Sign/Confirm/
 Ferrytown /Family/Event /40/Null/Null/Null/Null/

 Try to compare and match column 1 of file 1 and column 4 of file 2 and if it is match then 
 display all columns of both files such as this format:

file2 content/xxx/xx/40/x/x/x/x/ 40/3/file1 content/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/40/x/x/x/x/ 40/4/file1 content/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/40/x/x/x/x/ 40/8/file1 content/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/40/x/x/x/x/ 40/12/file1 content/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/40/x/x/x/x/ 40/20/file1 content/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/40/x/x/x/x/ 40/22/file1 content/x/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/40/x/x/x/x/ 40/30/file1 content/x/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/128/x/x/x/x/ 128/3/file1 content/x/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/128/x/x/x/x/ 128/4/file1 content/x/x
file2 content/xxx/xx/128/x/x/x/x/ 128/5/file1 content/x/x
.........................
...................................the list goes on


I am using awk instruction as follow:
```

> awk -F'/' ' NR==FNR{c[$1]=$2 FS $3 FS $4; next} {if ($4 in c)}{print
> $0, FS="*", c[$1]}' file
> 1 file 2

But the output appeared in this manner andI think something I have missed out from the
instruction:

```
Georgetown /Family/Event /40/Name of Activity/Date of Activity/Note/Sign/Confirm/
Ferrytown /Family/Event /128/Null/Null/Null/Null/Null/
Ferrytown /Family/Event /128/Name of Activity/Date of Activity/Note/Sign/Confirm/
Ferrytown /Family/Event /40/Null/Null/Null/Null/Null/

Thanks.
James.Ost
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your tried code and efforts. Please do format your question to make it more clear, as of now its sample of input and output is not clear, so kindly do edit it once and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is the desired answer because file2 has different number of fields, but it should be a starting point

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
awk \
  'BEGIN {
     FS="/"
     OFS=FS
     }
   FNR == NR {
     for (fi=1; fi<=NF; fi++) {
       gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$fi)
       v1[FNR]=sprintf("%s%s", (v1[FNR] == "" ? "" : v1[FNR] OFS), $fi)
     }
     file1[$1 SUBSEP $2]=v1[FNR]
     next
     }
   {
     for (fi=1; fi<=NF; fi++) {
       gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$fi)
       v2[FNR]=sprintf("%s%s", (v2[FNR] == "" ? "" : v2[FNR] OFS), $fi)
     }
     file2[$0]=v2[FNR]
     }
   END {
     for (fi2 in file2) {
       for (fi1 in file1) {
         split(fi1, afi1, SUBSEP)
         r=sprintf("%s%s%s", FS, afi1[1], FS)
         if (fi2 ~ r) {
           printf("%s %s\n", file2[fi2], file1[fi1])
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ' \
file1 \
file2
```